# merging two formgroups using concat not working in angular application

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am have created an angular form using reactiveforms. I have controls to be displayed on the left and right. The controls on the right are the ones prefixed with the word alternate and is displayed based on a selection of the radio button.
Hence I have created two FormGroups. So I load the first group on ngOnit and try to add the second group to the first when the user selects radio button as yes. Unfortunately I dont see that adding to the group and the form throws errors since it cant find the definition of the form control. I have tried using concat in the value changes but it doesn't seem to work.
I have also added a screenshot to show structure of the elements when they render in the browser.
Could somebody tell me what the problem could be ?

I have created a stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6xsgr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**Component**

```
accounts: FormArray;

    ngOnInit(): void {
     this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({

      accounts: this.formBuilder.array([]),
      bankContactName: [
        { value: null, disabled: this.readonly },
        requiredIfValidator(() => this.form && this.form.accounts.value.length > 0 && this.requiredSection)
      ],
      bankContactPhone: [
        { value: null, disabled: this.readonly },
        requiredIfValidator(() => this.form && this.form.accounts.value.length > 0 && this.requiredSection)
      ],
        this.addAccount();
        this.accounts = this.formGroup.get('accounts') as FormArray;
    }
       });
      addAccount() {
        this.accounts.push(this.createAccountForm());
      }
      
      createAccountForm(): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group(
          {
            yesNoMultilingual: [{ value: false, disabled: this.readonly }],
            bankAccountPurpose: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }, requiredIfValidator(() => this.requiredSection)],
            bankName: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }, requiredIfValidator(() => this.requiredSection)],
           }
         );
        
        
      createAlternateAccountForm(): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group(
          {
            alternateBankAccountPurpose: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }, requiredIfValidator(() =>
              this.form.yesNoMultilingual?.value === true)],
            alternateBankName: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }, requiredIfValidator(() => this.requiredSection)],
          }  
         };
        
        
        
         validation() {
         
        this.form.accounts.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            takeUntil(this.notifier$),
            tap((result) => {
              for (const control of this.accounts.controls) {
                if (control.get('yesNoMultilingual').value === true) {
                  this.accounts.controls.concat(this.createAlternateAccountForm())
                }
              
              }
            })
          )
          .subscribe();
         
         }
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="field boxed">
   <app-yes-no-multilingual name="yesNoMultilingual" formControlName="yesNoMultilingual" id="yesNoMultilingual">
   </app-yes-no-multilingual>
</div>
<div class="flex-group">
<div class="flex-2">
<div class="field">
   <label for="bankAccountPurpose" translate>
   details.bank-purpose
   </label>
   <input [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" type="text" name="bankAccountPurpose"
      id="bankAccountPurpose" formControlName="bankAccountPurpose" />
   <aa-alert alertClass="error" alertText="{{ 'common.required' | translate }}" *ngIf="
      (accounts.controls[i].get('bankAccountPurpose').touched || submitted) &&
      accounts.controls[i].get('bankAccountPurpose').errors?.required
      ">
   </aa-alert>
</div>
<div class="field">
   <label for="bankName" translate>
   details.bank-name
   </label>
   <input [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" type="text" name="bankName" id="bankName"
      formControlName="bankName" />
   <aa-alert alertClass="error" alertText="{{ 'common.required' | translate }}" *ngIf="
      (accounts.controls[i].get('bankName').touched || submitted) && accounts.controls[i].get('bankName').errors?.required
      ">
   </aa-alert>
</div>
<div class="flex-2" *ngIf="accounts.controls[i].get('yesNoMultilingual')?.value">
<div class="flex-group">
   <div class="flex-2">
      <div class="field">
         <label for="alternateBankAccountPurpose" translate>
         details.bank-purpose
         </label>
         <input [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" type="text" name="alternateBankAccountPurpose"
            id="alternateBankAccountPurpose" formControlName="alternateBankAccountPurpose" />
         <aa-alert alertClass="error" alertText="{{ 'common.required' | translate }}" *ngIf="
            (accounts.controls[i].get('alternateBankAccountPurpose').touched || submitted) &&
            accounts.controls[i].get('alternateBankAccountPurpose').errors?.required
            ">
         </aa-alert>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
         <label for="alternateBankName" translate>
         details.bank-name
         </label>
         <input [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }" type="text" name="alternateBankName" id="alternateBankName"
            formControlName="alternateBankName" />
         <aa-alert alertClass="error" alertText="{{ 'common.required' | translate }}" *ngIf="
            (accounts.controls[i].get('alternateBankName').touched || submitted) && accounts.controls[i].get('alternateBankName').errors?.required
            ">
         </aa-alert>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reactive forms work in a different way. It has its own set of methods, check out the api for formgroup to see what you can do with formgroups: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup You would want to use `addControl` for adding new controls to your form.

I would attach a change event to the radio button and react accordingly when the value changes. Seems you have it in a child component, so you need to bubble up the event to the parent with `@Output`, but according to your demo stackblitz:

```
      <div class="field boxed">
        <input type="radio" (change)="doChange(account)" [value]="true" formControlName="yesNoMultilingual"> Yes
        <input type="radio" (change)="doChange(account)" [value]="false" formControlName="yesNoMultilingual"> No
      </div>
```

Also notice I added brackets to `[value]` to capture the boolean value.

doChange function would then look like this:

```
doChange(control) {
  if (control.get('yesNoMultilingual').value) {
    const newForm = this.createAlternateAccountForm();

    Object.keys(newForm.controls).forEach(key => {
      (control as FormGroup).addControl(key, newForm.get(key));
    });
  }
}
```

Also you need to set the ngIf in templates to check that the actual formcontrol you are trying to display exists instead of checking that if the boolean value is `true`.

If you need to remove the controls added, you can use [`removeControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#removecontrol) in the same fashion.

Your forked **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axrydh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Oh wait, is that a formArray... need to edit

Comment: yes it is formarray

Comment: Yeah, should have been a minor change. Check now.

Comment: I am getting a compile time error Property 'addControl' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: updated, use `(control as FormGroup)`. AbstractControl is the baseclass for all controls.

Comment: addControl takes only two arguments and it is complaining that there are three arguments. What to do with  { emitEvent: false })

Comment: Well there is another issue too that I thought of... You also need to add a check that the controls do not already exist. What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: The version is Angular 11

Comment: At the moment the error that i am getting is global-error-handler.ts:8 Error Cannot find control with path: 'accounts -> 0 -> alternateBankAccountPurpose'

Comment: If I comment that control then it throws error of the next immediate control

Comment: There could be a race issue also... your if checks if `<div class="flex-2" *ngIf="accounts.controls[i].get('yesNoMultilingual')?.value">` instead check that the control itself exists that you are trying to display since the formcontrol is not available instantly when the radio button value changes

Comment: Other please provide a [mcve] so your code can be tested. Tried if there was an issue of needing to check if a control already exists, seems to not be an issue as I initially thought.

Comment: I have created a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6xsgr?file=src/app/app.component.html . I am able to reproduce that error  Cannot find control with path: 'accounts -> 0 -> alternateBankName

Comment: Hi @AT82  , did you get a chance to look at my stackblitz ?

Comment: Hi! Havent had time, was sleeping and now I'm not at work, but managed to squeeze it in now. Since you are using v11 `emitEvent` is not available, so you would end up with an infinite loop. So I would attach a change event instead to the radio button and react according to that. Also as said, you need in your ngIf check that the actual control exists that you are trying to display: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axrydh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for taking your time out . The solution works when applied to my application but unfortunately when I refresh the form , I get the same exception . Can’t find control . I tried to add the controls by calling it in OnInit but that doesn’t seem to help . Any ideas why that would be the case

Comment: Hmm... hard to tell, the stackblitz works when refreshing, so hard to say. Just sounds like there is somewhere a field exposed when the app is initialized. Check all your ngIf's. The error should say which field is causing error, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239052/discussion-between-tom-and-at82).